# Change Jenkins Installation path

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins installed by default on my Red Hat Linux Machine at below default locations using yum :-

```
Home - /var/lib/jenkins/
War - /usr/lib/jenkins/
```

I want to install another jenkins on same server at different location and port.

```
New Home - /app/jenkins/data/jenkins/
New War - /app/jenkins/bin/
log location - /app/jenkins/logs/
```

Any idea how we can mention path in yum while installing jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have four options here:

1. `yum --installroot=/opt/jenkins1 --releasever=<your_release_version> install jenkins`¹ You then can use [`chroot` together with Systemd](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/changing-roots) (very hacky)
2. Just download the [jenkins.war](https://www.jenkins.io/download/) and start it twice with different [start options](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#jenkins-parameters). [Use Systemd again](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6) two manage the services.
3. [Use Docker to create two instances](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#docker).
4. Instead of creating two instances, use Jenkins' different permissions models, e.g. [Matrix-based security](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security). Your can also [scale the instance then](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/scaling/).

I can understand, why someone needs two instances (different departments with different requirements), but you're gonna need to manage two Jenkins instances, so you should try to extend the abilities of your first instance.

(¹): I just checked the `dnf` command on my Fedora machine, but it should be the same for (even older) Red Hat